# Laravel @ Return(display) at blade_view SQL column_name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a tables:

- premium_status - where I have id, name (name of premium status First,
  Second, Third) and other columns
- user_status - where I have id     (sequence), user_id and
  premium_status (it displays ID from    premium_status)

Example from user_status:

- ID - 1
- User_ID - 1
- premium_status - 1
- end date - date when ends premium status

It means, that User_ID 1 has ID 1 and premium_status 1 (First)

So, website return at profile page:

```
You have status First which ends XXX
```

My question is how to display premium_status NAME and ENDDATE on another (not profile page)

I did the following:

```
<?php 
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $prostatus = DB::table('user_status')->select('premium_status')->get();
  dd($prostatus);
?>
```

It returns me that this userID has premium_status 1.

Now, I need to display premium_status NAME and ENDdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php 
       $id = Auth::user()->id;
       $prostatus = DB::table('user_status')
           ->select('premium_status.name', 'user_status.end_date')
           ->join('premium_status','user_status.premium_status', '=', 'premium_status.id')           
           ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, thnx! it returned
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1834 (2) { ["comment"]=> string(19) "Package 19 ["enddate"]=> string(19) "2019-01-17 18:56:32" } }

IF used var_dump($prostatus);

How, can I return only name + date?

Comment: Use `$results = json_decode(json_encode($prostatus), true);` to transform results to array, then use the values from array:
`$results = array_map(function ($value) {
                    return $value['name'] . '-' . $value['enddate'];
                }, $results);`

Answer (score 0):

I expect your models to be like this with relationships defined

```
class UserStatus extends Model
{
  public function premiumStatus ()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PremiumStatus');
  }
}

class UserStatus extends Model
{
   public function premiumStatus ()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\UserStatus');
   }
}
```

Now to get a status with its premium status

```
$status = UserStatus::with('premiumStatus')->first();
$status->name;
$state->end_date;
```